# How to free up space and see remaining storage?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, storage

Firstly, I seemed to have messed something up in the About This Mac storage tab as I can't see the remaining storage.as seen in this picture.

[image: Example image]

And while I'm at it, what is the best way to free up storage?

Comment: It is not clear from your picture and question what exactly the problem is. you can't actually "mess up" the storage tab as it is read-only. If you could fill in some details (edit the original question, don't add as a comment) on what is happening vs. what you are seeing, etc.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be enough free space to show on that graph. The drive looks *critically* full.